# node.js configure file syntax error line 433

Tags: node.js

I downloaded node.js through a link that was not joyent, and it gave me an old version of node. So I wanted to reinstall node.js with the new git://github.com/joyent/node.git. So I tried running the same clone script over and it gave a fatal error because my node folder isn't empty. So I deleted the node folder and ran it again and it cloned it.

After that I tried running the configure file and I got an error:

```
File "./configure", line 433
    fpu = 'vfpv3' if armv7 else 'vfpv2'
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea how to solve a problem? I've tried deleting the node folder and cloning the git again but same error.

Here is the code I found in the file near line 433:

```
armv7 = is_arch_armv7()
# CHECKME VFPv3 implies ARMv7+ but is the reverse true as well?
fpu = 'vfpv3' if armv7 else 'vfpv2'
```

Comment: isn't it easier to just download the package you want from http://nodejs.org?

Comment: I don't know how to do that through terminal.

Comment: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The issue was that the python script attempting to run the configure file was Python 2.4. So I installed Python 2.7 (I may have had it already), and I ran the script again using:

```
python2.7 configure
```

Then it ran correctly.

Comment: If you're like me and using CentOS, here's the next thing you'll need to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624511/upgrade-python-without-breaking-yum

Comment: In my case, python 3.3.4 was causing this issue. It is not compatible with python3.

Answer (score 1):

you could use curl to install it from terminal:

```
$ curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
$ ./configure --jobs=1 --prefix=$HOME
$ make install
```

install npm:

```
$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it turned out to be that I had an older version of python.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Samir's answer, here is what you might need to do.

```
python2.7 configure 
make PYTHON=python2.7
```

This will configure installation using python2.7 instead of your default python which is probably older than 2.6.

Alternatively after `configure` you can update top of you `Makefile` to use the same version of python

```
PYTHON ?= python2.7
```