# Multiple python versions: How to set default python binary

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiple-versions

I have installed python 2.7.5 on CentOS 6.4 which python 2.6 already installed.

Python2.7 is under /usr/local/bin and library configuration is correct as well.

I set alias in .bash_profile as

```
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python2.7'
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

However, I need to do `source .bash_profile` each time I logged in and it's pretty annoying.
How can I change my default python version to python2.7.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Logout from desktop environment, then login. And it will work.
(`.bash_profile` is not sourced when you login graphically.)

If that does not work put `alias` line to `.bashrc`.

Answer (score -1):

Create a symbolic link python in /usr/bin and point it to /usr/local/bin/python2.7. Something like this should work:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Make sure you have permissions to do that. Once done, hit python command and it should get you to python 2.7

Hope this helps.

Comment: Because some tools are dependent on default version of python, overwriting /usr/bin/python will break those tools.

Comment: I believe python 2.7 is completely backward compatible with python2.6 and below (unlike 3.x).

Comment: If dependent module is pure python, it will be run in Python 2.7. But if it is extension module, it will not.

Comment: Enen though the module is pure python, there could be problem. Imagine that there was some script name /usr/bin/abc which import module xyz. Module xyz is not installed for Python2.7, only for Python2.6 unless you manually install such modules. (/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xyz/....)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624511/upgrade-python-without-breaking-yum).

Comment: I agree with this. :)