# Cannot import modules after alt-install of Python 3

Tags: python, module

After I installed python3 using make altinstall as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624511/upgrade-python-without-breaking-yum) and [here](http://toomuchdata.com/2012/06/25/how-to-install-python-2-7-3-on-centos-6-2/) , when invoking python 3 I get this error: ImportError: No module named 'pymysql'. If I invoke python as $python (2.6 system version) it can import this module no problem. What could be the problem? Do I have to install all modules for python3 separately?

Thank you.

Comment: In brief It would be **yes** You have to install all modules for python3 separately

Comment: Thanks! Could you give some recommendations how to do that?

Comment: In the root directory of the module, `/path/to/python3 setup.py install`. Or, sometimes modules will give more specific instructions

Comment: Even if you install a new python 2.6 with altinstall you'd need to install a new copy of the modules (well, or symlink them, assuming you used the same compiler as the system python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief It would be **yes** as modules are installed in two different directories in different versions

for example the [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) module is located in:

- Python 2 : `C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk`
- Python 3 : `C:\Python33\Lib\tkinter`

Also for example let's take a look at the famous module [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) The developers [maintain](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.8.0/) 2 different versions for each version: *(assuming you have windows)*

Python 2 : http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.8.0/numpy-1.8.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download

Python 3 : http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.8.0/numpy-1.8.0-win32-superpack-python3.2.exe/download

This is because there are certain differences *(eg:how `print works`)* in these versions and If you install numpy for python 3.2 on python 2.7 It simply wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Life is not that easy :)