# Yum not working?

Tags: python, fedora

I have default python 2.7 and i try to install python3.3 and install pip3 and Django.now when i try to install others using yum i got this error.for a example yum update

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:
   No module named yum
Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.
It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.5 (default, Nov 12 2013, 16:18:42) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20131017 (Red Hat 4.8.2-1)]
If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

How can i fix this error?

Comment: You should not change the system python. `yum` relies on it. If you install a new python, put it in an alternative path. You can then use `virtualenv` to use the new python seamlessly.

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624511/upgrade-python-without-breaking-yum

Answer (score 19):

There is probably many python versions on your system and only one of them has the yum library installed. For some reason the python binary called when you run `yum` on the command line is not the one who has the yum library installed.

Find the list of python 2 binaries available on your system. Run as root:

```
find / -type f -executable -name 'python2*'
```

The output will probably look like that:

```
/usr/bin/python2.6
/usr/bin/python2.7
...
```

etc...

For each one of these, run

```
/usr/bin/python2.x
```

You'll get a python prompt.
Run:

```
>>> import yum
```

Do this for every python binary until you find one that doesn't raise an ImportError at this step.

Then find out what is the path that yum is using to run python.
This is the first line in the yum script. Run

```
cat `which yum` | head -1
```

You'll probably get:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Now, run as root:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.x /usr/bin/python
```

(replace python2.x with the good python version you found earlier).

Comment: You are right. But I need to use python2.7 instead of python2.6. How to make python2.7 the default python version?

Comment: That's the purpose of the `ln -s /usr/bin/python2.x /usr/bin/python` command I wrote in my answer. Replace /usr/bin/python2.x with the location of the python2.7 on your system. If it's not /usr/bin/python2.7, run `which python2.7` to find out where it is.

Comment: Of course, do this only if python2.7 is really supposed to be the default python on your system. If python2.6 is the python version  officially supported by your distro, you should keep it that way. Just run `python2.7 myapp.py` when you want to run an app with python2.7.

Comment: Yes. Then I can't use easy_install or pip any more, everytime I use python2.7 setup.py install

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.

`Yum` has been written in Python lang.

So when you upgrade your default Python to new version it will make problem for `yum`.
If you get `python --version` it will tell you 3.3.

For solving this problem , change `python` command to `python2.7`.

First check it:

```
user@host:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Sep 28  2013 /usr/bin/python -> python3.3
```

Try it:

```
mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python-origin
ln -s python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Then check it:

```
user@host:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Sep 28  2013 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

If you wish to install python3 in CentOS you should install that via source code.

```
download main source code via python.org website.
extract archive file.
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: when i try to run python --version it says Python 2.7.5

Comment: what is first line of `less /usr/bin/yum`?

Comment: did you tried to install `python3` via the main source code?

Comment: just i download python from the python.org

Comment: @user3480706 I upgraded my post , check it again.

Comment: i did that also same result :(

Comment: @user3480706 do you have python3 in your system? try it `whereis python3`

Comment: python3: /usr/bin/python3.3 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.3m /usr/lib/python3.3 /usr/lib64/python3.3 /usr/local/bin/python3.3m-config /usr/local/bin/python3.3 /usr/local/bin/python3.3m /usr/local/lib/python3.3 /usr/include/python3.3m /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz

Comment: @user3480706 ok. so what is your command that has error?

Comment: when i'm try to install packages using yum install it will give error

Comment: try it: `python -c "import site;print site.getsitepackages()"` it will give you list of all python packages (libs) directory. get `ls` to find `yum` module. and tell me the output of above command + your search result.

Comment: this is the out put and ther is no yum module ['/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/site-python']

Comment: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages-only have readme file,/usr/lib/site-python-in user/lib ther no folder called site-python,/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages- only have yum-metadata-parser

Comment: @user3480706 sorry I can't detect your problem. could you re-install yum via rpm package or via source code?

Comment: @user3480706 ;) have you re-installed yum ?

Comment: @user3480706 for making sure , change yum header from `python` to `python2.7` and then test it.